# Create a link that opens Word document on certain page

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, office365

I'm working with SharePoint 2013 and I want to use hyperlinks which open a Word document directly on a certain page.

I found that with PowerPoint slides, I can add **&wdslideindex=30** to the URL, and then the file is opened directly on slide number 30.

Is there a similar function in Microsoft Word?